# Where can I buy normal diodes?

Tags: diodes

Firstly apologies for any naivete in this post. I am not an electrical engineer, I just have a problem I am trying to solve.

I have a 12v power supply connected to a 5v "reducer" (which started off life as a car lighter port -> USB converter) connected to a device which draws 500ma and has an internal battery. In the event that the connection from the 12v -> reducer is lost, currently will flow in the opposite direction to the reducer. I'm not sure what is drawing current, there is an LED "on" light which remains lit when the 12v is disconnected, but for this application I want no current to flow from the device -> reducer as it is important to conserve the device's battery supply.

So I thought a need a diode, rated for 500ma / 5v forward and maybe also a reverse rating (let's say 10ma / 3v - the device's battery is 3v and the reducer draws 10ma).

Searching for "5v 500ma diode" on eBay comes up with no results, mainly Zener diodes which I don't want. "assorted diodes" is flooded with listings for LEDs and "junction diodes" returns quite a few listings for rectifier diodes but my supply is already DC so I don't know if these are the right solution.

When I search for "assorted resistors" I can pick what I need, but when searching for diodes I can't find any listings for standard "PN" or "junction" diodes.

Comment: Mouser, Digikey, and Newark are are some of most common distributors with the largest selection

Comment: You don't want 5 V forward on the diode. If you got that, then after connecting it to your "reducer", the actual load you want to provide power to would get nothing. You want the lowest forward voltage you can get, which might be 0.3 or 0.4 V if you pick a Schottky diode. You probably want substantially more than 5 V reverse rating.

Comment: You will also have trouble finding a diode with only 5 volts reverse rating. Try, let's say, 30 to 50 volts for Schottkys, or 50 volts for regular diodes. And 500 mA is quite low for a forward current limit. Try looking 1 A or more.

Comment: What exactly is a "reducer"? I could not understand anything. Could you draw a schematic? Most likely you're looking for a 1N4007 general purpose rectifier diode, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Indraneel Thanks, a 1N4007 looks like the one I need, there are a lot of results online for that. Two questions: is a rectifier the right choice if my input is already DC? Is the "maximum voltage drop" a constant drop or a temporary dip? e.g. if the voltage drop is 1V, will a 5v supply turn into a 4v supply, or will it dip to a minimum of 4v then back to ~5v? Thank you.

Comment: The volt drop on a diode is pretty much constant, at around 0.6V for a silicon diode in normal use.  So your 5V would become approximately 4.4V.

Comment: If you need a lower drop than 0.6V, you will need a 1N5819 schottky. But be careful as the reverse voltage is only 40 V.

Comment: @Indraneel what is the normal solution when you need a diode with 0 voltage drop? A transformer before the diode?

Comment: @Frayt A transformer only works with AC, not DC so you would not take that approach. An op-amp can be wired up in a circuit to simulate the behaviour of an ideal diode with zero voltage drop, but this is only useful at signal level currents, not for current to actually power something.

Comment: @Frayt For power level currents it's trickier. In this case, a 0V drop diode is implemented as a MOSFET with auxilliary circuitry to make it behave as a diode. There are a few instances where you can just use just a MOSFET and maybe one resistor, but that is highly dependent on exactly where the "diode" is required and the circuit around it. In general it requires a bunch of auxiliary circuitry that literally monitors the voltage around the MOSFET and switches on when the voltage is in the right direction, and off when the voltage/current is in the wrong direction.

Comment: @Frayt you say you have a 12V source. Draw us a circuit diagram.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a Schottky diode. 
A normal diode would also do the job, but has about 700mV drop between the anode (the "input") and the cathode (the "output"). So if you put 5V in you get 4.3V out, which may or may not be a problem. A good example of a normal diode is the 1N4007, which can handle 1A and 700V.

A Schottky diode has a reduced forward drop, which is about 50% of a normal diode, because it uses a metal-semiconductor barrier. If you're interested you can read up on it on wikipedia.

There are many distributors of electronic components out there. Farnell and RS components have UK warehouses, Digikey and Mouser ship from the U.S. All of them are good choices to search for schottky diodes but unfortunately they all charge quite high shipping costs if you order less than about 50$ worth.

So I would recommend going to eBay and typing in Schottky Diode. Any diode with more than 500mA will do. Standard Voltages range from 20V - 100V. Lower Voltage and higher current is usually better (less forward voltage drop at your current). I'd recommend something in the 2A-3A and 20V-40V range. Don't use SMD parts unless you have a board to solder them to. And unless you have a lot of time don't buy in China/Hong Kong/Malaysia/etc. - it takes ages to ship to Europe.

Comment: don't go to ebay for components. You'll get scammed. Simple as that. Arrow.com has free shipping, even for small orders, and is from the same category as Mouser and Farnell (in fact, Arrow owns Farnell afaik).